# PHP AJAX sort array without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, sorting

I have the following code which runs a query on an XML file and returns the results. I then sort it using usort. (my sort functions are on a seperate page sort.php). I have commented out the usort for now but the usort function works as its intended to.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

//RUN QUERY ON XML
$xQuery = $xml->xpath($query);

//DISPLAY RESULTS OF QUERY

$i = 0;
//usort($xQuery, 'sortMake');
    for ($f = 0; $f <= 9; $f++) {               
        ?>
            <img src= "<?php echo $xQuery[$i]->MainPhoto;?>"><br />
            MAKE:  <?php echo $xQuery[$i]->Make;?><br />
            Model: <?php echo $xQuery[$i]->Model;?><br />
            $i++;


    <?php } ?>
```

So the above code would display all the content unsorted. I would like to have a sort link before the loop that when clicked would sort the array and display it without reloading the entire page. I know its probably something with AJAX but all of the AJAX resources I have found are all examples of functions that use MySQL. I am not using MySQL.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Since you tagged your question with jQuery, can you add sorting on the client side? Does your data get put into a table or list?

Comment: I tagged jQuery because from what I understand its AJAX and jQuery which are used to have events on the page done without having to reload the page. If its wrong I will remove the tag. The data is in a PHP array which is then displayed in a html table. I did not post all the HTML in order to keep the post brief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [jQuery's .get() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).  That should atleast get you pointed in the right direction.  jQuery is a Javascript library, and can definitely be used for your purpose.  Javascript alone could also accomplish the task, however jQuery's goal is to simplify your life by minimizing the amount of coding you have to do.  You will have to either download or reference the jQuery library in your `<head>` tag.  You should definitely read up on selectors and how they are used as well if you really want to start using jQuery.

**Personally** I love jQuery and have used several other libraries.  I found jQuery to be great for beginners and the online documentation is fantastic.  It has a huge group of users that can answer any and all questions for you.

Bascially, you need to wrap the displayed data in a tag that jQuery would be able to find, ie :

```
<a href='#' id='link'>Sort Data</a>
<div id='xmlData'>...DATA...</div>`
```

Then have your script:

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    $.get('xmldata.php',function(d){
        $('#xmlData').html(d);
    });
});
```

Then have a script entitled `xmldata.php` with the content:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

//RUN QUERY ON XML
$xQuery = $xml->xpath($query);

//DISPLAY RESULTS OF QUERY

$i = 0;
usort($xQuery, 'sortMake');
for ($f = 0; $f <= 9; $f++) {               
    ?>
        <img src= "<?php echo $xQuery[$i]->MainPhoto;?>"><br />
        MAKE:  <?php echo $xQuery[$i]->Make;?><br />
        Model: <?php echo $xQuery[$i]->Model;?><br />
        $i++;
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Another question though, I have multiple sort methods in 'sort.php'. So 'sortMake' will not be the only one I use. Will I need multiple pages similar to xmldata.php ? Or is there a way I can get a value in xmldata.php from the link?

Comment: $("#link").click(function(){
$.get('xmldata.php?sort=sortMake',function(d){
$('#xmlData').html(d);
    });
});

Would I be able to $_GET['sort'] on xmldata.php?

Comment: `$.get('xmldata.php',{sort:'sortMake'},function(){/*function stuff*/});` and yes you would be able to.

Comment: Yeah, you should totally use jQuery. I hear Jon Skeet invented in just 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I'm having trouble. I just want to make sure I'm doing things correctly. I put the script in the head of the document after I include the jquery library. Is the href='#' correct? Because when I click it nothing happens except a '#' gets appended to the URL. I'm using jquery-1.7.min.js. The link and the div tags have their ID's and everything seems to match the above code, but nothing is happening.

Comment: If your JS in in the `head` it needs to be inside: `$(document).ready(function(){});`.  If it is just in the body, it needs to be AFTER the link and div tag.

Comment: Ahh, I see. You've been very helpfull. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort it on the page without AJAX or PHP sorting.  You'll need to modify your HTML slightly.  Put the results in a parent element with an id.  Put each result in a div with a class.  Put the data you want to sort on in spans with a class:

```
<div id="carList">
    <div class="car">
        <img src= "<?php echo $xQuery[$i]->MainPhoto;?>"><br />
        MAKE:  <span class="make"><?php echo $xQuery[$i]->Make;?></span><br />
        Model: <span class="model"><?php echo $xQuery[$i]->Model;?></span><br />
        $i++;
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

To sort the elements, first put them in an `Array`:

```
var listEl = $("#carList");
var cars = listEl.children(".car").get();
```

Then call `.sort()` on your `Array`.  You'll create a custom comparison function to pass to `.sort()`:

```
cars.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aMake = $(a).find(".make").text();
    var bMake = $(b).find(".make").text();
    return a - b;
});
```

Now, just append the elements back to the parent element:

```
listEl.append(cars);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/ZNmEh/

Comment: I like it.  Very simple and gets the job done quite effectively.